# query sql error on pentaho data integration (subquery)

Tags: mysql, pentaho

this is my sql query

```
SELECT 
p.Product_Name, d.year4
COUNT (fact_order.sk_product)
FROM 
(SELECT * FROM fact_order limit 0,5000) fo , product p , dim_date d
WHERE fo.sk_product = p.sk_product and fo.sk_order_date = d.date_key and fo.sk_product = ${product_name}
GROUP BY fo.sk_product, d.year4
LIMIT 0,2000
```

i hope to show product based years

Answer (score 0):

try

```
SELECT p.Product_Name, d.year4, COUNT(fo.sk_product)
  FROM (SELECT * FROM fact_order limit 0, 5000) fo, product p, dim_date d
 WHERE fo.sk_product = p.sk_product
   and fo.sk_order_date = d.date_key
   and fo.sk_product = ${product_name}
 GROUP BY fo.sk_product, d.year4,p.Product_Name LIMIT 0, 2000
```

Answer (score 0):

Missing **,** for your query:

```
SELECT 
p.Product_Name, d.year4,COUNT (fact_order.sk_product)
FROM 
(SELECT * FROM fact_order limit 0,5000) fo , product p , dim_date d
WHERE fo.sk_product = p.sk_product and fo.sk_order_date = d.date_key and fo.sk_product = ${product_name}
GROUP BY fo.sk_product, d.year4
LIMIT 0,2000
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the error is in the clause `WHERE`. You are doing `fo.sk_product = ${product_name}`. 
If I'm not wrong, you should to compare `sk_product` (I guess it is an integer) with another 
`sk_product`, not with a `product_name` (that it is a String).

As in the fact table you have the `sk_product`, I would do `fo.sk_product = p.sk_product`.
Further, in your `SELECT` you have `p.Product_Name`, but it isn't in `GROUP BY` clause. If you want to get the product names in the rows, replace `fo.sk_product` with `p.product_name` in `GROUP BY`, or if you want to get the surrogate keys instead of the names of the products, replace `p.Product_Name` with `p.sk_product` in the `SELECT` clause.

You must to think that to get the products by `product_name`, this column must to be UNIQUE.

The query would be something like this (getting by `sk_product`, and `sk_product` as parameter):

```
  SELECT 
        p.sk_product, d.year4, COUNT(fact_order.sk_product)
        FROM 
        (SELECT * FROM fact_order limit 0,5000) fo, product p , dim_date d
        WHERE fo.sk_product = p.sk_product and fo.sk_order_date = d.date_key and fo.sk_product = ${sk_product_parameter}
        GROUP BY p.sk_product, d.year4
        LIMIT 0,2000
```

Or like this (getting by product_name if product_name is UNIQUE for each sk_product):

```
SELECT 
p.Product_Name, d.year4
COUNT (fact_order.sk_product)
FROM 
(SELECT * FROM fact_order limit 0,5000) fo , product p , dim_date d
WHERE fo.sk_product = p.sk_product and fo.sk_order_date = d.date_key and p.product_name = ${product_name}
GROUP BY fo.sk_product, d.year4
LIMIT 0,2000
```